# Redirect from Apache to Tomcat with mod_proxy

Tags: apache-http-server, tomcat

I have a domain with correctly configured DNS's called **mydomain.com** that points to my Ubuntu 16.04.3 server in **11.11.11.11**, so when I introduce **mydomain.com** in a browser, I get to the default page of the Apache installed in such server.

I also have a Tomcat 7 installed in the same server with a **JSF** APP running on it, so when I introduce **http://11.11.11.11:8080/myappname/** in my browser my APP appears in the browser.

I would like to redirect from Apache to my Tomcat, so everytime someone writes **mydomain.com** on its browser my APP appears.

In order to do so, I have installed and configured **mod_proxy** according to many tutorials I have read (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333252/sending-redirect-in-tomcat-web-application-behind-a-apache-2-proxy-mod-proxy) or [this other](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-as-a-reverse-proxy-with-mod_proxy-on-ubuntu-16-04) ). My configuration in the .CONF file of the Apache default site is:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/myappname/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/myappname/
```

With this configuration, everytime I write **mydomain.com** in the browser, the main page of my **JSF** APP is shown, BUT IN PLAIN TEXT WITHOUT PICTURES/CSS AND ANY URL OR DYNAMIC PART WORKS.

If I check the "performance" section in Mozilla tools I can see a lot of errors like these:

```
http://www.mydomaincom/myappname/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.xhtml[HTTP/1.1 500 Internal server error]
http://www.mydomaincom/myappname/images/EN.png [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 249ms]
```

In the other hand I have discovered that with this config:

```
ProxyPass /myappname 127.0.0.1:8080/myappname 
ProxyPassReverse /myappname 127.0.0.1:8080/myappname
```

everytime I write in my browser **mydomain.com/myappname** the page shows well and no error are thrown. Obviously I don't want to use such configuration, I would like to write JUST **mydomain.com**

I have tried MANY other mod_proxy configurations with other parameters (ProxyRequests, DefaultType, ProxyPassReverseCookiePath, ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain...) but none of them seems to work...

What is the problem?

Thanks in advance for your patiente and help!

BTW: I know that Tomcat shouldn't be publicly exposed, I will take care of it later...

Answer (score 0):

Add a RewriteRule

```
RewriteRule ^/$ /myappname
```

in combination with the `ProxyPass /myappname`.